# How does the Classification and regression decision tree works?

Tags: python, r

I'm beginner who is learning data science.

May I know how does the classfication and regression decision tree works? 
I wonder how does the decision tree is computed from classfication up to the projection. (e.g isit the projection is based on the mode of a specific group? (classification decision tree); isit the mean of a specific group? (regression decision tree)

I Want to know the theory behind the decision tree.
Thanks

Comment: That is not really the right question for this forum...this is about working with code and data to get you there. Here is a link to a [Google Machine Learning Video] (https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjeuYT_1ODYAhUG7GMKHbdIBd0QtwIIRjAG&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DLDRbO9a6XPU&usg=AOvVaw0PyHtNDKPoJW6yBLZjgtRb) which gives you the basics. If you really want to understand, by a good book, watch a few videos and try building a model from scratch if you can.

Comment: Noted about what to ask in this forum and Thanks for the information and advice sconfluentus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These links pretty much explains the workings of a decision tree. 
http://dataaspirant.com/2017/01/30/how-decision-tree-algorithm-works/ 
https://medium.com/machine-learning-101/chapter-3-decision-trees-theory-e7398adac567

These were just a google search (Decision tree theory) away. So, please put in some research before posting a question here.

Comment: Hi Anuj Gautan. I did google search but still i couldn't understand.
By the way, Thanks for the information.

Comment: If you are really trying to understand the theory behind decision trees, I suggest this course in coursera: https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning-data-analysis. This is fourth course of the specialization, but it is understandable on its own and has a week's content on Decision Trees.

Comment: Another good idea could be to read a book. "Machine Learning with R" is nicely written and gives a good introduction to several kinds of algorithms.

Comment: Thanks Anuj Gautam for sharing the link and suggestion.

Comment: Thanks Geogery for your suggestion. 

Comment: @Stephen If my answer has actually helped you, could you please mark my answer as correct?